# The more privilege, the higher in the list

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables: `users` (http://prntscr.com/g1n8gh), `games` (http://prntscr.com/g1n8cw).

How to make it so that the games show above when `creator` has the higher `privilege` value.

Comment: Databases store things, they don't show anything. What UI tech are you using for display? How are you retrieving the data? What specific part of this is causing you difficulty? Perhaps you could post some code.

Comment: I use php for this. But for the best kind I want to do it all in one request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
SELECT * from games INNER JOIN users ON games.creator = users.id  order by 
users.privilege desc
```

Comment: I tried to do "INNER JOIN users", but did not think of what to do vice versa. Thank you very much for the help!